# Give correct permissions to make

Tags: permissions, dependencies, make

I'm on Linux Subsystem for Windows/Ubuntu and I'm trying to follow [a tutorial](https://github.com/nebulasio/wiki/blob/master/tutorials/%5BEnglish%5D%20Nebulas%20101%20-%2001%20Installation.md) and I am stuck at this part :

```
cd /usr/local/bin/
wget https://github.com/golang/dep/releases/download/v0.3.2/dep-linux-amd64
ln -s dep-linux-amd64 dep
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/nebulasio/go-nebulas
make dep
```

I get the following error here:

```
[sudo] password for stepseazy:
dep ensure -v
make: execvp: dep: Permission denied
Makefile:54: recipe for target 'dep' failed
make: *** [dep] Error 127
```

I'm not quite sure what is going on here as I don't quite understand the make command and how it works.

Comment: ... so what does `ls /usr/local/bin/dep-linux-amd64` say?

Comment: It says /usr/local/bin/dep-linux-amd64 I don't think it exists I tried cd there

Comment: dep-linux-amd64 is a file with numbers in it

Comment: Apologies that was meant to be `ls -l /usr/local/bin/dep-linux-amd64`  (to get a listing with permissions - so we can check it is executable; I don't think`wget` usually preserves executable permissions - curious that  the tutorial doesn't mention `chmod`ing it)

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7970784 Oct 19  2017 /usr/local/bin/dep-linux-amd64

Comment: Ok, I changed permission, it works now...

Comment: How did you know it was that file?

Comment: Deduced from the message `dep: Permission denied` when `dep` was just made as a symbolic link in `/usr/local/bin`